# Randomly generating numbers within a fixed non-Gaussian distribution in matlab

Tags: matlab, random, matrix, generator, permutation

I have an 200 x 200 data matrix (symmetrical about x=y), where the position of each value in the matrix is important. The matrix is filled with values between -0.2 and 0.8, non-normally distributed.

I am trying to generate a random model from these to test whether the outcome variable I get by doing some operation on the values in my 200 x 200 matrix is significant. I figured the best way to do this would be to define the distribution of values and then create a random matrix from these. I think this would probably be better than just randomly permuting the values in the upper triangle of my matrix (and faster)? Anyone know how to do this? I will need to repeat this for many thousands of matrices with different non-gaussian distributions, so a fast solution would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your Matlab code so far?

Comment: I don't have any code currently - not sure how to go about this one. I can share my matrix, or part of it if that helps? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand what you are trying to do (maybe consider inserting line-breaks/paragraphs in your question). `rand(200)` will give you a `200x200` matrix of random values.

Comment: Why you should *randomly permuting the values in the upper triangle of my matrix*? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You say that "the position of each value in the matrix is important," but what does that mean? Is the distribution independent of the position of the values in the matrix? Or does the location of the values in the matrix play a role in the distribution?

Comment: Is this "data matrix" some form of covariance matrix or correlation matrix? If so, you might look at [this PDF article](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/unpublished/Visualization.pdf) and investigate the [Wishart distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution).

Comment: The way you compute this "outcome variable" is important. Is this some sort of statistic that depends on the columns (or rows)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments. Yes it is a correlation matrix where each row/column represents a position in space. There are a number of outcome variables I compute, but all depend on the position in space, i.e. the row/column number. I want to show that the outcome variable could not occur by chance by randomly generating numbers from the same distribution...

Answer (score 0):

Not *quite* sure what you are asking precisely, but I guess you could take a look at the `random()` function in the statistics toolbox:

```
>> help random
```

> RANDOM Generate random arrays from a specified distribution.
>       R = RANDOM(NAME,A) returns an array of random numbers chosen from the
>       one-parameter probability distribution specified by NAME with parameter
>       values A.
>
> ```
> R = RANDOM(NAME,A,B) or R = RANDOM(NAME,A,B,C) returns an array of random
> numbers chosen from a two- or three-parameter probability distribution
> with parameter values A, B (and C).
>
> The size of R is the common size of the input arguments.  A scalar input
> functions as a constant matrix of the same size as the other inputs.
>
> R = RANDOM(NAME,A,M,N,...) or R = RANDOM(NAME,A,[M,N,...]) returns an
> M-by-N-by-... array of random numbers for a one-parameter distribution.
> Similarly, R = RANDOM(NAME,A,B,M,N,...) or R = RANDOM(NAME,A,B,[M,N,...]),
> and R = RANDOM(NAME,A,B,C,M,N,...) or R = RANDOM(NAME,A,B,C,[M,N,...]),
> return an M-by-N-by-... array of random numbers for a two- or
> three-parameter distribution.
>
>
> NAME can be:
>
>    'beta'  or 'Beta',
>    'bino'  or 'Binomial',
>    'chi2'  or 'Chisquare',
>    'exp'   or 'Exponential',
>    'ev'    or 'Extreme Value',
>    'f'     or 'F',
>    'gam'   or 'Gamma',
>    'gev'   or 'Generalized Extreme Value',
>    'gp'    or 'Generalized Pareto',
>    'geo'   or 'Geometric',
>    'hyge'  or 'Hypergeometric',
>    'logn'  or 'Lognormal',
>    'nbin'  or 'Negative Binomial',
>    'ncf'   or 'Noncentral F',
>    'nct'   or 'Noncentral t',
>    'ncx2'  or 'Noncentral Chi-square',
>    'norm'  or 'Normal',
>    'poiss' or 'Poisson',
>    'rayl'  or 'Rayleigh',
>    't'     or 'T',
>    'unif'  or 'Uniform',
>    'unid'  or 'Discrete Uniform',
>    'wbl'   or 'Weibull'.
> ```
>
> --snip--

Generating an N-by-N matrix of random values from the log-normal distribution  with `mu = 0` and `sigma = 1` for example, goes like this:

```
N = 5;
A(triu(true(N))) = random('logn', 0,1, N*(N+1)/2, 1);
A(tril(true(N))) = A(triu(true(N)));
```

Comment: Thanks for this - the problem is that I want to write my own distribution function from a population sample, i.e. the distribution is non-Gaussian but cannot be defined by any of default options... any ideas?

Comment: @user2524828: ah, I misunderstood then -- you want to find the PDF from given data? In that case, you might want to look at [ksdensity](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/stats/ksdensity.html?s_tid=doc_12b). Read [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25144/generate-a-probability-distribution-from-a-histogram-with-two-peaks-in-matlab) on Cross Validated for more options.

Comment: Thanks - couldn't find this function before posting!